# Minipage and graphics

Tags: titles, minipage

Hi everyboy I'm trying yo make a thesis titlepage, and I'm modifying a thesis class to have the things on my own way, so I want to put two images on the left of the page and the text on the right, I'm using `minipage` enviroment I have this code.
Main:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,chap,oneside,openright]{thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\shorthandsspanish}{}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\bfseries}

%\usepackage[left=4.00cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\makeindex % para que cree el índice (pero aún no decimos dónde)
\begin{document}
\include{Portada}
%\include{Dedicatoria} %agregar al indice
%\include{Agradecimientos} %Agregar al indice   
%\include{Resumen}
%\include{Abstract}
\include{Objetivos}
\include{Justificacion}
\include{Estado}
\include{Desarrollo}
\include{Biblio}
\end{document}
```

Portada

```
 % Supply information for use on title page:
 \institute{INSTITUTO POLITÉCNICO NACIONAL}
 \school{ESCUELA SUPERIOR DE INGENIERÍA \\ MECÁNICA Y ELÉCTRICA}
 \thesistitle{"Sistema de pulsioximetría con múltiples longitudes de onda y 
  detección síncrona"}        
  \author{Ing. David González Gamboa}        
 \degree{Maestría en Ciencias en Ingeniería Electrónica} 
 \department{Fotónica} % provide your area of study here; e.g.,
   %  "Mechanical Engineering", "Nuclear Engineering", "Physics", etc.

  \signaturelines{3}
  \projadviser{Dr.  José Manuel de la Rosa Vázquez} % For a masters project 
    use \projadviser instead of \thadviser,
  \memberone{Isaac Newton}        
  \membertwo{Copernicus}
   %\memberthree{Aristotle} % must change signaturelines to 4 if using this 
   4 members

  \submitdate{Ciudad de México, Enero de 2019 }        
  \copyrightyear{}   % if omitted, current year is used.        

   \titlepage
```

thesis class

```
\def\titlepage{%
     \pagenumbering{roman}
     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \ifnum\numcomm<4 \vglue .5in\vfil \fi  % masters
     \ifnum\numcomm>5 \hbox{ } \vspace{-24pt}\fi % make more space on page
    \begin{minipage}[t][4cm]{0.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{escudo}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ESIME}
    \end{minipage}
   \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
         \begin{singlespace}
        \begin{center}
            \parindent=0pt
            {\large\uppercase\expandafter{\@institute}}\\ [12pt]
            \@school \\[12pt]
            \@thesistitle \\
            \@author\\ [12pt]
            A \doctype Submitted to the Graduate\\ [8pt]
            Instituto Polit\'{e}cnico Nacional\\ [8pt]
            in Partial Fulfillment of the\\ [8pt]
            Requirements for the Degree of\\ [8pt]
            \uppercase\expandafter{\@degree}\\ [8pt]
            Major Subject:~~\uppercase\expandafter{\@department}\\ 
            \ifnum\numcomm < 7 \vskip 32pt \else \vskip 24pt \fi
            \sigblock 
            \ifnum \numcomm < 7 \vskip 32pt \else \vskip 24pt \fi
            Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute\\
            Troy, New York\\ [14pt]
            \ifnum\numcomm>6 \vskip -8pt \fi
            \@submitdate
        \end{center}
    \end{singlespace}
 \end{minipage}
     \newpage
     \pagestyle{plain}
%    \pagenumbering{roman}
%    \setcounter{page}{2}
}
```

I get this

[image]

And I want something like this

[image]

Without the borders of course any idea about how to do this ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The clip at the top will be difficult ;-) I also see dead people amongst the members... And now for seriousness: Please don't post fragments of code only. Provide `\documentclass{...} \begin{document}....\end{document}`, all compilable!

Comment: Ok then this is my principal code

Comment: There are 1000000000000000000000 `thesis.cls`, because everyone thinks he/she is very clever and his/her class is unique. But each one is different. Which one do you use? ;-)

Comment: Ok you are telling that I am stupid, http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/docs/latex-thesis/ this is the link, just, here is the thesis class, http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/docs/latex-thesis/thesis.cls, in fact the only thing that I nees us the titlepage declaration.

Comment: No, I am not telling you are stupid. The point is that all of those classes are meant to be specific for some university and ate called thesis -- nobody can guess which university is meant

Comment: The code you posted isn't enough to compile it correctly, I tried but I've got a lot of errors like `! Undefined control sequence.` on `\institute`, `\school`, etc. please post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Otherwise, I think it's impossible to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples/blob/master/mosquito.png